Intellij “Parsing Java” notification, slow to build JavaFX project after MacOS Sonoma Upgrade
Recently I upgraded MacOS from Monterey to Sonora.  One of issues after upgrading is slowness in the build process to launch JavaFX window in debug “Run” mode.  Anytime I make a change to the code, even putting a newline, and “Run” the code, I receive a “Parsing Java” notification.  This can take up to 10 - 20 seconds.
Prior to the upgrade, I never saw a “Parsing Java” notification and the JavaFX window opened within 2 seconds.
NOTE: I have been developing JavaFX on IntelliJ for several year, and never experienced this type of issue.  It was only after I upgraded my MacOS to Sonoma that this happened.  I use an M1 Mac with 32GB Memory, never any issue until upgrade to Sonoma.
INTELLIJ
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-241.14494.240, built on March 28, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+8-b1207.12 aarch64
MAVEN
Version 3.9.6
JAVA
Java 1.8.0_4028
Azul Zulu OpenJDK (JDK FX) for Mac ARM 64-bit
(OpenJFX is included by Zulu)


Please refer to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235. Contact the support team with the sample project, the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) and the CPU snapshots for IntelliJ IDEA and the build processes.

What versions? Java, OpenJFX, IntelliJ, Maven/Gradle.

Hi Basil, I put some more info in the post.

I just recently (yesterday) upgraded my IntelliJ setup from a 2023 version.  When it did that it said (in a pop up dialog or welcome message on restarting idea) that the release explicitly included fixes for functionality related to Sonoma.  So try an upgrade as suggested by TheRyan’s answer.

Hi Jewels, thanks but I've upgraded to 2024 - IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 (Community Edition), just today, and same issue.  Still working on it.  (will adjust original post to say 2024)

Could be M1 mac specific as I am using x64.

Thanks Jewelsea.  I've made some progress.  I am using the latest Java 8/OpenJFX and the issue happens.  But I just tried Java 21/OpenJFX (my code builds in Java 21 too), and the build has no problem, the issue is gone.  Therefore, the issue exists when using Java 8, but only on Sonoma.  Not sure if it's a Sonoma, Java 8, or Intellij bug.

You can add a self answer if you wish.

Almost 2 months later, I finally found the issue and solved the problem.  I noticed everytime I would launch the Javafx program (after an edit), an mdns network query was sent to determine my own laptop's IPv6 address.  Using a series of commands such as 'sudo networksetup -setv6automatic Wi-Fi' I enabled the IPv6, found the address, and added it to /etc/hosts.
ff90::2b37:3015:1402:8ab3 My-MacBook-Pro-2.local
Now the launch happens less than a second everytime (even when I shut off wifi and the mdns is sent over loopback).
